# /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion parse error

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am facing an error when run $ source ~/.bashrc. The error is /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1512: parse error near `|'.

bash_completion file (the first line is 1512) :

```
       if ! [[ "$i" =~ ^\~.*|^\/.* ]]; then
            if [[ "$configfile" =~ ^\/etc\/ssh.* ]]; then
                i="/etc/ssh/$i"
            else
                i="$HOME/.ssh/$i"
            fi
        fi
```

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please confirm that you are trying to source the file into a bash shell (ex. `echo $0`)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing. I did that to myself:

```
(^\~.*|^\/.*)
```